# Adverb for doing a routine action so familiar as to not require thought

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs

Adverb for doing something that is so routine you don't have to think about it - like driving a car or riding a bicycle - something you do out of habit and can perform without having to think about the steps.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. There is a term 'muscle memory' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_learning but I have no idea how to make an adverb out of it. 'Automatically' springs to mind.

Comment: Not an adverb, but "second nature"  is commonly used to describe skills that  have been fully integrated into one's system.

Comment: No one has suggested "instinctively"?

Answer (score 1):

You do it *mechanically* or *on autopilot*.

> **mechanically** [adverb]
>
> ...
>
> 2 Without thought or spontaneity; automatically.
>
> ‘the words are repeated mechanically’
>
> ‘I nodded mechanically’

{[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mechanically)}

> **on automatic pilot** [also **on autopilot**]
>
> In an intuitive way, without having to think about one's actions,
> generally because one has done something many times in the past. Also
> used in the shortened form, "on autopilot."
>
> *By the second week of data entry, I could fill in the spreadsheets on
> automatic pilot.*
>
> *Making bottles, changing diapers, and putting the baby to sleep were
> all challenging at first, but now I feel like I'm doing it all on
> autopilot.*

{[Collins COBUILD Idioms Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+autopilot)}

Comment: A little more figurative is "robotically".

Answer (score 0):

How about 'habitually'? Often used to mean a repetitive activity but reasonable to use in the context you describe I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

**rotely**  [Your Dict](http://www.yourdictionary.com/rotely) & [Int'l Dict](http://international-dictionary.com/definitions/?english_word=rotely) & [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rotely)

> mechanical, routine; in rote fashion

And an interesting article: [Language Log](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/005035.html) timely, rotely etc ...